# How to drop multiple databases by name,date with sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

The code below,list all the databases that exist and fetch them into an array,same thing for the tables of each database listed.Then it creates new databases and tables,containing every value of the older db and tables,but with th extension _backup-(a certain date).

```
$sql="SHOW DATABASES";
$query=mysql_query($sql,$connect);              
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $sql2="SHOW TABLES FROM ".$row['Database'];
    $query2=mysql_query($sql2, $connect);            
    $sql3 = "CREATE DATABASE `".$row['Database']."_backup-".$d."`";
    $query3=mysql_query($sql3,$connect);                                                    
 while( $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2) ) {   
  foreach($row2 as $rand2) { 
  $sql4 = "CREATE TABLE `".$row['Database']."_backup-".$d."`.`".$rand2."` SELECT * FROM `".$row['Database']."`.`".$rand2."`";
  $query4=mysql_query($sql4,$connect);
  }              
 }   
}
```

This code works as a backup,but the only thing that i cant figure out is how to drop the older databases.Lets say we trigger this script today (10.9.2014),and this code will creates a backup db1_backup-10.0.2014 for the original database named db1,if we trigger it today again,it will make backup of the previous backup,and thats a nasty thing,so **i need to drop the previous backup,after the new backup is created,and keep the original db of course**.I could really use your help guys,please.Thank you.

Comment: no one ?? any idea??

Comment: this script that i'm trying to create,is like a test for me.Believe me that i would choose the easiest path if it was for personal purpose,but i have to do it like this,and i really need some help,because i'm very close.I would place a bounty,but my rep is 4 pts lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `DROP DATABASE` before below code

```
$sql="SHOW DATABASES";
$query=mysql_query($sql,$connect);              
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    //Blacklist these to not make backup 
    if(! in_array($row['Database'], array('mysql', 'information_schema', 'performance_schema')) && strpos($row['Database'], "_backup-".$d) === false) {
        $sql2="SHOW TABLES FROM `".$row['Database']."`;";
        $query2=mysql_query($sql2, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
        $dropDb = "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `".$row['Database']."_backup-".$d."`";
        mysql_query($dropDb, $connect);
        $sql3 = "CREATE DATABASE `".$row['Database']."_backup-".$d."`";
        $query3=mysql_query($sql3,$connect) or die(mysql_error());                                                    

        while( $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2) ) {   
          foreach($row2 as $rand2) { 
            $sql4 = "CREATE TABLE `".$row['Database']."_backup-".$d."`.`".$rand2."` SELECT * FROM `".$row['Database']."`.`".$rand2."`";
            $query4=mysql_query($sql4,$connect);
          }              
        }
    }
}
```

That way there will be only one copy of backup for same date

**Update :** You are getting `mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource` because it was missing back ticks `` in table name of $sql2 & keep database name length below **16 character**

Tested and working

Comment: isnt working: "mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource on line 78" , line 78 is this "while( $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2) )"

Comment: yes,i explained in my question how it works,and why i need to drop previus backup

Comment: of course i added the mysql_query besides what you have done prevously,because without a query it is useless,but is not working,it gives me that error

Comment: try `$query3=mysql_query($sql3,$connect) or die(mysql_error());` and post what you got

Comment: "mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource" on code line "while( $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2) )" , i dont think the problem is with the drop statement,but with the code after while

Comment: i did it,and now it no longer backup the info_schema,perfo_schema,mysql which is a good thing,but also it doesnt delete the previous database backup,i will edit my question to take a look at the entire code

Comment: it helped,but it still doesnt solve the problem,thanks anyway

Comment: @Memphistoles You delete your backups first with this solution, then take a backup. What if something goes wrong during backup? Think about it...

Comment: @fancyPants , this script backup the original db first.Next, it should drop the previous backup,and do a new backup of the original db.I dont see the problem...

Comment: What makes you think so? The code I see above does a `drop database if exists...backup` first, then creates the backup database again. I'm just curious. You said, you do this for a test. What is this test? Is it because you're in a new job or something? Have you considered that the correct answer to the test might be to **not** reinvent the wheel? I mean, if they want to see how good of a coder you are, there sure are some better "tests" to determine that.

Comment: @fancyPants , the above code,isnt the entire code,the drop part will trigger only if the databases pass a certain condition.